# javah ActionBarAtivity class not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to get Android studio to work with NDK, when I want to create the jni and header using javah like this :

```
javah -d jni -classpath /home/user/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact/libs/android-support-v4.jar:/home/user/Android/Sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact/libs/android-support-v7-appcompact.jar:/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKt/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug com.example.user.ndkt.MainActivity
```

I get this error: 
Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
  class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found
I know lots of people have asked this question but I've read all posts and tried all answers suggested on stackoverflow for this issue, but none of them solved my problem. (I've tried changing directory to src, putting jar files with full path , putting just folder path to jars with out jars itself, changing permission and .... )

When I build a project with min SDKversion : 22 , there is no problem and every thing works fine.

but I need a project which works on API 19. in API 22, ActionBarActivity is deprecated.
does anyone has a solution for how to get this to work on API19 or bellow ?

Comment: I would suggest that you write the `JNI` yourself. I am guessing you are following a tutorial and they suggested you use `javah` to easily generate a few files for you. Also, you should be using `AppCompatActivity` but they did not `prune` `ActionBarActivity` from [tag:appcompat].

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating header files my self

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead of ActionBarActivity. Actually, ActionBarActivity was deprecated in favor of AppCompatActivity.